# Android send log lines as an email periodically

Tags: android, logging

I want to send the log lines to email in every 10 minutes.

To do that, I have used a Timer and inside of timer I send the logs via email.

However I loose some log lines between 2 emails.

For example my first email contains no lines which is normal according to my algorithm.

My second email contains log lines between 15.37 and 15.38 seconds.

My third email contains logs in between 15.44 and 15.48 time intervals.

My fourth email contains logs in between 15.55 and 15.58 time intervals.

As you can see I loose some of my logs but I could not find a way to avoid that.

Following is my code in my service class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mTimer = new Timer();

    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            sendLogFile();

        }
    }, 0, 1000 * 60 * 10 );

}
```

Inside of sendSupport method the second parameter is sent as a content of the log lines where logs is a static string variable.

```
private void sendLogFile() {

    mInteractor.sendSupport("LOG FILE", "MSG"+logs, "SUBJECT"+ System.currentTimeMillis(), "",

            result -> {

                Timber.log(Log.DEBUG, "sendSupport Thread.currentThread().getName() " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                if (result.isSuccess) {

                    Timber.d("is sent");

                    writeLogFile();

                } else {

                    Timber.d("is NOT sent");

                }
            }

    );

}



private void writeLogFile()
{

    try {

        StringBuilder logBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "logcat -d");

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        String line;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            logBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }

        logs =  logBuilder.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As a result I could not figure out how am I going to be able to get all logs in periodically in my email.

Thanks.

Comment: Still waiting for ideas..

Comment: Do you want to send logs between those 10 minutes or whole log?

Comment: I would try to save the logs into a database table, when the timer fires I will try to read the logs from the table and send the email using Async Task.

Comment: what about rotating files of logs, create 2 files for logs - write into one after 10 min make a switch, start writing to the other - send and clear the first. My guess is you lose data due to the long time it takes to preform internet action, if you switch it to internal action and let go of you connection dependency it will help (it is still not 100% loss proof)

Comment: Hi @Hilal, did you have a chance to look at the proposed solution with FileTree? Please, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 4):

While the @Knossos answer is pointing the reason why some logs are missing, it doesn't suggest how to use that knowledge to reliably get the logs from users' phones, when you don't have an access to their devices to run some `adb` commands.

Here is what I suggest to do instead:

1. As you do already use `Timber`, just add some more power to it. Namely, add an additional `LoggingTree` that will save the logs into a file, instead of just posting them to Logcat. You can have many Timber Trees working simultaneously, so you can have both Logcat and File logs if needed.
2. Use the same timer to send an email message when and where needed. But, instead of using access to `logcat -d`, simply use the file where Timber have already written the logs. Don't forget to flush the stream before sending the email. In order not to send the same logs again and again, configure the `FileTree` in a way that it creates a new file every time when a previous one is sent (seta a new file name via a method call, for example).
3. Profit :)

To log into two different systems (Trees), you need to simply add one more to Timber:

```
Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
Timber.plant(new FileLoggingTree());
```

And here is an example of `FileLoggingTree`([source](https://sureshjoshi.com/mobile/file-logging-in-android-with-timber/)):

```
public class FileLoggingTree extends Timber.DebugTree {
    private static Logger mLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileLoggingTree.class);
    private static final String LOG_PREFIX = "my-log";

    public FileLoggingTree(Context context) {
        final String logDirectory = context.getFilesDir() + "/logs";
        configureLogger(logDirectory);
    }

    private void configureLogger(String logDirectory) {
        // reset the default context (which may already have been initialized)
        // since we want to reconfigure it
        LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        loggerContext.reset();

        RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender<>();
        rollingFileAppender.setContext(loggerContext);
        rollingFileAppender.setAppend(true);
        rollingFileAppender.setFile(logDirectory + "/" + LOG_PREFIX + "-latest.html");

        SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP<ILoggingEvent> fileNamingPolicy = new SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP<>();
        fileNamingPolicy.setContext(loggerContext);
        fileNamingPolicy.setMaxFileSize("1MB");

        TimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent> rollingPolicy = new TimeBasedRollingPolicy<>();
        rollingPolicy.setContext(loggerContext);
        rollingPolicy.setFileNamePattern(logDirectory + "/" + LOG_PREFIX + ".%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.html");
        rollingPolicy.setMaxHistory(5);
        rollingPolicy.setTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy(fileNamingPolicy);
        rollingPolicy.setParent(rollingFileAppender);  // parent and context required!
        rollingPolicy.start();

        HTMLLayout htmlLayout = new HTMLLayout();
        htmlLayout.setContext(loggerContext);
        htmlLayout.setPattern("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}%level%thread%msg");
        htmlLayout.start();

        LayoutWrappingEncoder<ILoggingEvent> encoder = new LayoutWrappingEncoder<>();
        encoder.setContext(loggerContext);
        encoder.setLayout(htmlLayout);
        encoder.start();

        // Alternative text encoder - very clean pattern, takes up less space
//        PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
//        encoder.setContext(loggerContext);
//        encoder.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
//        encoder.setPattern("%date %level [%thread] %msg%n");
//        encoder.start();

        rollingFileAppender.setRollingPolicy(rollingPolicy);
        rollingFileAppender.setEncoder(encoder);
        rollingFileAppender.start();

        // add the newly created appenders to the root logger;
        // qualify Logger to disambiguate from org.slf4j.Logger
        ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger root = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
        root.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        root.addAppender(rollingFileAppender);

        // print any status messages (warnings, etc) encountered in logback config
        StatusPrinter.print(loggerContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected void log(int priority, String tag, String message, Throwable t) {
        if (priority == Log.VERBOSE) {
            return;
        }

        String logMessage = tag + ": " + message;
        switch (priority) {
            case Log.DEBUG:
                mLogger.debug(logMessage);
                break;
            case Log.INFO:
                mLogger.info(logMessage);
                break;
            case Log.WARN:
                mLogger.warn(logMessage);
                break;
            case Log.ERROR:
                mLogger.error(logMessage);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `logcat -d` is only delivering you the latest X bytes of data from the stream. You aren't guaranteed to get everything between 10 minute intervals.

In the best case, you get what you want. In the worst cases, you miss log data or log sections overlap (you get some from the previous dump too).

You can see this here: `adb logcat -d | dd`

```
...
03-27 11:36:27.474   791 22420 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (147, <unspecified>/0)
03-27 11:36:27.612  3466  3521 I PlayCommon: [657] alsu.c(187): Successfully uploaded logs.
453+111 records in
499+1 records out
255863 bytes (256 kB, 250 KiB) copied, 0,136016 s, 1,9 MB/s
```

As you can see, it is clearly a 256 kB chunk that is pulled through `logcat -d`.

On the plus side, you can change that! If you look at `adb logcat --help` you can see options.

For example, if you use `adb logcat -d -t '100000' | dd` (all logs in the last 100000 seconds. I now have the following:

```
...
03-27 11:45:41.687   791  1106 I netd    : bandwidthSetGlobalAlert(2097152) <0.90ms>
03-27 11:45:42.098 21897 23376 V FA      : Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2237+1558 records in
2879+1 records out
1474408 bytes (1,5 MB, 1,4 MiB) copied, 1,20785 s, 1,2 MB/s
```

1.5 MB of logs. You should be able to get all logs with this.

You log the timestamp of each logcat pull, then use that each time to determine the seconds since the last pull.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score -2):

You cannot send an email from the device without user interaction or implementing the email function yourself that allows to do this without user interaction.

Most apps have some api endpoint to send the logs to.

Comment: I am using an android box and I am able to send it. Are you telling that, that is the reason I loose my logs?